# read first line of the file and compare it with a string in shell file

Tags: shell, unix

I need to read first line of a file and match it with a text. If the text matches, I need to do certain operation.

Problem is if command is unable to compare the variable with the string.

```
file_content=$(head -1 ${file_name})
echo $file_content
if [[ $file_content = 'No new data' ]]; then
    echo "Should come here"
fi
echo $file_content
if [ "${file_content}" = "No new data" ]; then
  echo "Should come here"
fi
```

The if block is not working. I tried all possible syntax of if. I think the value that I am capturing in line 1 has some issues. Please help.

Comment: What is the first line in the file, including leading and trailing white space, if any? Is the `file_name` correct? Use `echo "<$file_content>"` to see everything and place `set -x` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
case $file_content in
  (*No new data*)
     echo "No news is good news."
     ;;  
  (*)
     echo "Yay, breaking news."
esac
```

This would ignore any leading/trailing white space. This has the benefit of not forking expensive `sed` commands to just remove a few characters. That's like delivering a few sugar cubes with a flat bed truck...

Answer (score 0):

There was trailing spaces.
Used the command
file_content="$(echo -e "${file_content_init}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
and then file_content was trimmed string that I used to compare.